# nest .key in dplyr deprecated, what to use instead

Tags: r, dplyr

In the recent `dplyr` version (1 <= ) the .key argument got deprecated.

In the docu they write that:

```
.key Deprecated lifecycle: No longer needed because of the new new_col = c(col1, col2, col3) syntax.
```

I do not use new_col syntax but the group_by (I do know the key column but col1, col2 etc might differ).

How do I change the code below so that it still does the same but does not produce the deprecated warning?

```
data <- data.frame(key= rep(letters,2), a = runif(2*length(letters)), b = runif(2*length(letters)))
data %>% group_by(key) %>% nest(.key="myData")
head(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

In `nest` , now you need to specify the columns which you want to turn into list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% group_by(key) %>% nest(myData = c(a, b))

#   key   myData          
#   <chr> <list>          
# 1 a     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 2 b     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 3 c     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 4 d     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 5 e     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 6 f     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 7 g     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 8 h     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 9 i     <tibble [2 × 2]>
#10 j     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# … with 16 more rows
```

Or remove the columns which you don't want to turn into a list :

```
data %>% group_by(key) %>% nest(myData = -key)
```

---

However, I don't know why they deprecated `.key` in `nest` and replaced it in another new function `nest_by` which works the same.

```
data %>% group_by(key) %>% nest_by(.key="myData")
#OR
#data %>% nest_by(key, .key="myData")
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have to specify each column name.  An easier option is with `group_cols`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(key) %>%
    nest(my_data = -group_cols())
# A tibble: 26 x 2
# Groups:   key [26]
#   key   my_data         
#   <chr> <list>          
# 1 a     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 2 b     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 3 c     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 4 d     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 5 e     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 6 f     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 7 g     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 8 h     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# 9 i     <tibble [2 × 2]>
#10 j     <tibble [2 × 2]>
# … with 16 more rows
```